# purple links in simple css dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am styling a very simple CSS drop down menu I found online, the problem is that I cannot make the text links to get colors, they all are just purple text. Here is the CSS code:

```
/* DROPDOWN MENU */
ul.menu {padding:0;margin:0;list-style-type:none;}
ul.menu >li{float:left;}
ul.menu >li>a{display:inline-block;padding:7px 7px 0px 7px;text-decoration:none;}
.last {border-right:solid 3px #282828;}
ul.menu >li>a:hover{color:#777;
}

ul.menu li ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
ul.menu li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    color: #010101;
}

ul.menu li ul li a:link{
    padding: 15px 20px;
    display: block;
/*    height: 40px;*/
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #010101;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
ul.menu li ul li a:hover{
    background: #555;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

And now here is the HTML code

```
<ul class="menu">


    <li>
        <a href="#"><div class="buttons">Stötar</div></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">försvar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Illustrations</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="buttons">Gäng</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="buttons">Staden</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="buttons">Fängelse</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="buttons">Shopping</div></a></li>

    <li><a href="#"><div class="active">Beskydd</div></a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#"><div class="buttons">Konto</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

If we put this code in a JSFiddle it looks ok and it seems like it can be fixed but when testing it in Google Chrome the link are just purple

JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/k49edo16/

UPDATE:
It happens only on visited, any idea how to fix this ? ( I am new to CSS )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
ul.menu li ul li a:hover{
    background: #555;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

with

```
ul.menu li ul li a{
    background: #555;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: you mean changing > ul.menu li ul li a:link < to > ul.menu li ul li a < ?

Answer (score 0):

Add color to for main links:

```
ul.menu >li>a
```

and add next line for sub-menu links.

```
ul.menu >li>ul>li>a{color:red;}
```

```css
/* DROPDOWN MENU */
ul.menu {padding:0;margin:0;list-style-type:none;}
ul.menu >li{float:left;}
ul.menu >li>a{display:inline-block;padding:7px 7px 0px 7px;text-decoration:none; color:red;}
ul.menu >li>ul>li>a{color:red;}
.last {border-right:solid 3px #282828; }
ul.menu >li>a:hover{color:#777;
}

ul.menu li ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    color:red;
}
ul.menu li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    color: #010101;
}

ul.menu li ul li a:link{
    padding: 15px 20px;
    display: block;
/*    height: 40px;*/
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:red;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
ul.menu li ul li a:hover{
    background: #555;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">


    <li>
        <a href="#"><div class="buttons">Stötar</div></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">försvar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Illustrations</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="buttons">Gäng</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="buttons">Staden</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="buttons">Fängelse</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="buttons">Shopping</div></a></li>

    <li><a href="#"><div class="active">Beskydd</div></a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#"><div class="buttons">Konto</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The only problem is that it changes all links to the same color and I want the main links in one color and the sublinks in other, but your idea is good anyway

Comment: @jagvillintesaga Read my answer again. You have code for main links and submanu links, edit this color:red  that suits your needs. I have clearly made difference between those two.

Answer (score -2):

could this be because the links are visited? You might need to set additional css classes for a:active, a:visited etc.

Comment: Yeah it is on visited, how to fix this ?